# Include values from application.properties in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, application.properties

I am trying to parameterize my build.gradle file with variables from my applications.properties file. Let's say I have a variable: flyway.user that is set in application.properties. How can I include this in the build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

My view - This is the other way around.

Gradle build + flyway - would only apply in local DEV / CI build.
All other ENV will drive via non-gradle tools.

its better to keep ENV defined in GRADLE_HOME (~/.gradle) gradle.properties
During build these are available in gradle project - to all tasks

Also - you can tokenise the application.properties and replace values (for DEV)
additional benefit is that if multiple developers are working - each can have their own config without any code change.

~/.gradle/gradle.properties >> gradle :project >> tasks (flyway, processResources)

(I use the above - for my flyway in our team)